# How to achieve same line heights in firefox and chrome?

Tags: html, css

When using same font, chrome and firefox give them different line heights, and sometimes you need them to be the same across browsers... Right now when encountering this issue, i have to give both font size and line height in pixels, but it doesn't seem like the best solution. Should different units be used may be? How do i make chrome and firefox render fonts similarly?

Comment: Do you have an example we could look at?

Answer (score 0):

You can set line height as a pure number, which will by definition be taken as relative to the element’s font size, e.g. `line-height: 1.2`.

You can alternatively use the `em` unit, e.g. `line-height: 1.2em`, but then inner elements would inherit (unless they have their own line height set) the computed value, not the relative number. This matters if nested elements have different font sizes, and usually it’s the relative line height that should be used.

Answer (score -1):

Please use a CSS reset from Yahoo, that should resolve cross browser issues.